# Spring WebSocketStompClient won't connect using SockJsClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

So, i was trying to replicate sockJs code from an excellent example by Rossen Stoyanchev here: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/load/StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.java

However, i've encountered an issue in that it won't connect to Stomp endpoint. Execution freezes on `stompClient.connect()`, no further debug messages are shown, not even from the Handler.

Here's my code:

```
public void waitForGreet() throws Exception {

    String stompUrl = "ws://127.0.0.1:61613/stomp";

    StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

    HttpClient jettyHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    jettyHttpClient.setMaxConnectionsPerDestination(1000);
    jettyHttpClient.setExecutor(new QueuedThreadPool(1000));
    jettyHttpClient.start();

    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(2);
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(webSocketClient));
    transports.add(new JettyXhrTransport(jettyHttpClient));

    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();

    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
    //WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter(Charset.defaultCharset()));
    stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[]{0, 0});
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);

    stompClient.connect(stompUrl, handler, "localhost", 61613);
}
```

If i use `WebSocketStompClient` it all works fine.

The issue can be reproduced with ActiveMQ, so i assume it's not Artemis-specific. I run this app using Spring Boot and i haven't specifically configured anything, it worked just fine with `WebSocketStompClient`.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem, i would greatly appreciate any insight or suggestion on how i can fix this. Am i missing some additional broker/spring-app configuration here?